# Как стилизовать скроллбар на странице

Tags: html, css, html5

Увидел такое в шаблоне ***Essential*** и хочу спросить, как стилизовать скроллбар справа? Вот картинка. Он на ней синий и толще, а не как стандартный. Картинка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/   это самый лучший плагин из всех известных мне

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Да, плагин хороший, но это с использованием скриптов (это не плохо, если что), а я просто думал, что можно без скриптов.

Comment: нет... кроссбраузрно нету...не получится

Comment: @МаксимЛенский  Кстати да, в Firefox скроллбар обычный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать только css стилизировать получиться для -webkit и ie(для ie не все есть возможности стилизации как в -webkit)

Для firefox увы нет стилизации - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547260

Пример

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-height: 2000px;
  /* style for ie */
  scrollbar-base-color: #26ACD3;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #26ACD3;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-track-color: #fff;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #26ACD3;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #26ACD3;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #26ACD3;
}
/* style for -webkit- */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(15,67,83,0.3);
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #26ACD3;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #26ACD3;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
```